# .net - import an excel file and remove certain rows

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking to upload an excel file, open it and the read through each row and possibly remove that row depending if one cell contains certain values.

I already have the upload working:

```
    Protected Sub ButtonUploadFile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonUploadFile.Click
        If FileUploadExcel.HasFile Then
            Try
                FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelImport.xls"))
                LabelUpload.Text = "Upload File Name: " & _
                      FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                     "Type: " & _
                     FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentType & _
                     " File Size: " & _
                     FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>"
            Catch ex As Exception
                LabelUpload.Text = "Error: " & ex.Message.ToString
            End Try
        Else
            LabelUpload.Text = "Please select a file to upload."
        End If
    End Sub
```

So I have it at moment called ExcelImport.xls

```
        Dim oExcelApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim sFileName As String = "~/ExcelImport.xls"
```

This is as far as I've got ...but not entirely sure about the rest.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a third party library for your excel parsing. Unless you have a requirement to access it via COM interface...
The library I found some time ago is open source and gives me just enough flexibility to do what I need to in excel.
Check out [this link](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) for the library itself and a quick example on how to use it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows (or columns) with `Range`:

```
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.WorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
Dim xlWS As Excel.WorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(sheet), Excel.Worksheet)

Dim xRng As Excel.Range = CType(xlWS.Rows(rowIndex), Excel.Range)
xRng.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use Excel Interop an a server: It is slow, prone to "hangs" and Microsoft strongloy advises against it.
Sure it seems "easy" but its maintanabillity is so bad, that you will have headaches for years to come.
Do yourself a favour and use something like the free Library EPPLus which can read xlsx files magnitudes faster and is far easier to use.